# skip one notification, repeating each day

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I'm making an app, reminding user to do smth each day, and I can't implement the situation , when notifications are shown or not shown depending on some condition even if the app is in background mode.
one possible variant is to set endless repeating notifications:

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.NSDayCalendarUnit
```

but then some method is required to skip notification for present day if some condition was satisfied. If one removes these notifications from Notification Center they won't fire next day.

The other way is to make some method creating notification only for present day, and then removing them if some condition is satisfied. The problem is, this method should create these scheduled notification even being in background mode, and I have no idea how to make that.

Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way you can wake up your app at a specific time is through a [silent APNS push](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/). This means you need a server that will send silent pushes to your device, the user needs to have internet and the user needs to opt out for push.

Maybe [background fetch](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/multitasking/) will work for you ? With Background Fetch your app gets woken up every minimum interval. You could set your app to wake up every x minutes and check that condition.

```
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:100]; //seconds
```

Please beware that:

> The minimum number of seconds that must elapse before another
>   background fetch can be initiated. This value is advisory only and
>   does not indicate the exact amount of time expected between fetch
>   operations.

Comment: I found this code in tutorial :
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(
      UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
as I understand, this method doesn't guarantee even one fetch operation a day, and I need at least one.
Or did I miss smth?

Comment: It doesn't guarantee anything. The only way you can find out how the OS works with the background fetch is to test it yourself - or find an article on that.